# What is the best way to teleport back and forth between your current location and your base?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What is the simplest, most effective way to be able to teleport to your home base and then return to the location you were at before, i.e. from point A to B and back to A.

The method must be mobile so you can take it with you on adventures, and I would prefer a pay once item.

Comment: Ask around the cities and towns to see if anyone has seen a chicken-like creature with a human-like head named [Ooccoo](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Ooccoo). ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be or travel with a 9th level wizard who has the [Teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport) spell.

Otherwise, get some [Boots of Teleportation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-teleportation) (or scrolls)

Both of them do not account for inter-planar travel, have a limit on distance, and a chance to fail.

The spell Greater Teleport removes the distance and failure problem (I estimate boots of greater teleport to be 3 times the cost of the normal boots of teleport) but not the inter-planar travel problem.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility that will mostly solve this problem is a [Bag of Holding III](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding) and a set of [Ring Gates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/ring-gates).  What you do is you have all of your party members but one hop into the bag of holding, and then have the remaining one drop the bag through one end of the ring gate.  Have the 'home team' either send a signal or return to the bag at a predetermined time, and the 'away team' can pull the bag back through.

You can pass 100 lbs of material through the ring gate per day, and the Bag III only weighs 35 lbs, so you can do this once per day.  You're limited to 100 miles, and you have to leave at least one person on the far end, so this isn't totally ideal, but it's reasonable.  This would cost 47400 gp.

Comment: I think you could pass the bag back through and have the remaining character climb in and be brought through too: 'A character can reach through to grab things near the other ring…'. You would have to leave the other ring behind, although you do want that so you can get back again.

Comment: The boots of Teleportation cost less and have a longer distance although this is a good alternative. Kinda risky as most adventurers have many pointy things.

Comment: @Aaron the cost is about the same. (boots of teleport are actually slightly more expensive). This does have the up side of guaranteed arrival at the correct destination.

Comment: @Aaron This may not be the best way of teleporting home, but it certainly is one way of teleporting home. :)

Answer (score 4):

At higher levels a [*Well of the Welcome Respite*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/well-of-the-welcome-respite) could work, being specifically designed for this purpose.  It also has the advantage of turning/rebuking Grammar Nazis.

If your home base is a finite demiplane, however, an [*Amulet of the Planes*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-the-planes) might be even better choice however, as long as someone in the party has 20 INT, in that you don't have to leave a portal behind.

A [*Mirror of Mental Prowess*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/mirror-of-mental-prowess) is, however, the best choice-- if you can afford it.  Placed in your home base with a loyal operator, the Mirror allows you to just verbally ask for a portal home and have your loyal staff open one for you.  Not only is this method completely invisible until employed, it's also completely immune to any trouble you might be having on your adventures; even getting disjunctioned by your enemies, stripped of your belongings, knocked unconscious, and left for dead on the side of the road wont prevent your loyal minions from showing up to rescue you once nobody's looking as long as that road isn't also in an antimagic field. Just make sure your mirror operating people are *very* loyal, and your home base is *very* secure.

All of these have the advantage over lower priced suggestions that they can be used a large number of times per day, limited only by the time it takes to use them or the physical limitations of movement through a portal.